# Delayed Job Capistrano task without restarting each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job

How is this possible?

I am currently using Capistrano recipe that comes with [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Rails-3-and-Capistrano)

This is what I have:

```
# Delayed Job recipes
require "delayed/recipes"

set :rails_env, "production" # added for delayed job

after "deploy:stop",    "delayed_job:stop"
after "deploy:start",   "delayed_job:start"
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:restart"
```

I don't understand very well Capistrano phases, maybe solution is to set right task to right phase.

## Update

Every time I deploy I get

```
executing `delayed_job:restart'
```

Is this really needed? Is there a way to restart delayed_job just when needed? or is it always needed?

Comment: I didn't understand what is the problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also not sure what you're looking for but maybe a simple

```
cap delayed_job:stop
```

from the command line will do? You can see all available tasks at

```
cap -T
```

**UPDATE**

I would argue that it is a best practice to restart your Delayed Job workers every time you deploy. In the end, the workers execute your code, and that tends to change between deploys. Now, if the code your workers run rarely changes (that includes the rails boot process, environment files, initializers, settings, models that you use, etc.) and you want to take care of this yourself, then simply remove the hooks such as

```
after "deploy:stop",    "delayed_job:stop"
```

from the deploy.rb and you're fine: the dj tasks will still be at your disposal, but they will not be triggered during deploy.